# How to obtain the last path segment of a URL

Tags: go, path, uri, segment

I have following url:

```
targetUrl := "http://google.com/foo/bar?a=1&b=2"
myUrl, err := url.Parse(targetUrl)
```

I wonder how I can obtain last path segment (`bar`) from `myUrl.Path`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [path.Base](https://godoc.org/path#Base) to get the last element of a path:  `path.Base(myUrl.Path)`

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/_zw3n_TXv0s).